# Why '$3t \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies t \equiv 4 \pmod 5$' is true in resolving congruence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to resolve this system of equations

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x & \equiv & 1 & \pmod 3\\
x & \equiv & 3 & \pmod 5\\
x & \equiv & 2 & \pmod 7\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I have solution for this, but there is one step, highlighted, which I don't understand

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies x = 3t + 1$$
$$3t + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \implies \color{red}{3t \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies t \equiv 4 \pmod 5} \implies t = 5u + 4 $$

and so on.

Comment: $3t=2\implies 6t=4\implies t=4$ (all $\mod 5$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$3t \equiv 2 \equiv 12 \pmod 5.$$

Recall the rule of division modulo $n$

> If $\text{gcd}(a,n) = 1$ and $ab \equiv ac \pmod n$, then we have $b \equiv c \pmod n$.

Applying this with $a = 3$ and $n = 5$, we have
$$3t \equiv 12 \pmod 5 \implies t \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$$